# PHP result produces an Array sometimes not and I'm getting this error "Cannot use string offset"

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am getting an inconsistent result, sometimes I am getting an array and sometimes I think I am not getting an array because it triggers this kind of error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/loc/public_html/mysite.com/directory/home/test.php on line 25
```

This is my code:

```
$result = $response['Items']['Item'];
    $html = "";
    foreach( $result as $k => $v ){
        if(isset($v['MediumImage'])) {
            $image = "<img src='".$v['MediumImage']['URL']."' />";
        }else if(isset($v['LargeImage'])) {
            $image = "<img width='150px' height='150px' src='".$v['LargeImage']['URL']."' />";
        }else {
            $image = "<img src='css/no-image.jpg' />";
        }
        $html .= "<div class='container'>";
        $html .= "<div class='imgContainer'><a href='".$v['DetailPageURL']."'>".$image."</a></div>";
        $html .= "<h3 class='newaps'><a href='".$v['DetailPageURL']."'><span class='lrg bold'>".$v['ItemAttributes']['Title']."</span></a></h3>";
        if(isset($v['ItemAttributes']['Feature'])){
            $html .= "<div class='item-features'>";
            $html .= "<ul>";
            foreach( $v['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] as $feature ) {
                $html .= "<li>".$feature."</li>";
            }
            $html .= "</ul>";
            $html .= "</div>";
        } else {
            $html .= "<div class='item-features'>";
            $html .= "<span class='no-data'><a href='".$v['DetailPageURL']."'>More info on this item...</a></span>";
            $html .= "</div>";
        }
        $html .= "<div class='clear'></div>";
        if(isset($v['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice'])){
            $html .= "<div class='item-price'>Price: ".$v['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']." ".$v['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['CurrencyCode']."</div>";
        }
        $html .= "<div class='trackSalesRank' id='".$v['ASIN']."'>Track Sales Rank</div>";
        $html .= "</div>";
```

**Line 25 is** `$image = "<img src='".$v['MediumImage']['URL']."' />";`

This is the array value of `$response`:

```
Array
(
    [OperationRequest] => Array
        (
            [HTTPHeaders] => Array
                (
                    [Header] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => UserAgent
                            [Value] => PHP-SOAP/5.3.19
                        )

                )

            [RequestId] => 74dd6e53-5455-4852-8b19-72580b3f244d
            [Arguments] => Array
                (
                    [Argument] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Service
                            [Value] => AWSECommerceService
                        )

                )

            [RequestProcessingTime] => 0.319231
        )

    [Items] => Array
        (
            [Request] => Array
                (
                    [IsValid] => True
                    [ItemSearchRequest] => Array
                        (
                            [ItemPage] => 1
                            [Keywords] => B0083PWAPW
                            [ResponseGroup] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Images
                                    [1] => ItemAttributes
                                )

                            [SearchIndex] => All
                        )

                )

            [TotalResults] => 1
            [TotalPages] => 1
            [MoreSearchResultsUrl] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?camp=2025&creative=386001&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fsearch%3Fkeywords%3DB0083PWAPW%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Daws-amazon-aps&linkCode=sp1&tag=elson06-20&SubscriptionId=AKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ
            [Item] => Array
                (
                    [ASIN] => B0083PWAPW
                    [ParentASIN] => B008GGCAVM
                    [DetailPageURL] => http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Fire-HD/dp/B0083PWAPW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                    [ItemLinks] => Array
                        (
                            [ItemLink] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => Technical Details
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Fire-HD/dp/tech-data/B0083PWAPW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => Add To Baby Registry
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB0083PWAPW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => Add To Wedding Registry
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB0083PWAPW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => Add To Wishlist
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB0083PWAPW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => Tell A Friend
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/B0083PWAPW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => All Customer Reviews
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/review/product/B0083PWAPW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Description] => All Offers
                                            [URL] => http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B0083PWAPW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ%26tag%3Delson06-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB0083PWAPW
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [SmallImage] => Array
                        (
                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL75_.jpg
                            [Height] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 75
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                            [Width] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 75
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                        )

                    [MediumImage] => Array
                        (
                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL160_.jpg
                            [Height] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 160
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                            [Width] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 160
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                        )

                    [LargeImage] => Array
                        (
                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL.jpg
                            [Height] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 500
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                            [Width] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => 500
                                    [Units] => pixels
                                )

                        )

                    [ImageSets] => Array
                        (
                            [ImageSet] => Array
                                (
                                    [SwatchImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL30_.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 30
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 30
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [SmallImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL75_.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 75
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 75
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [ThumbnailImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL75_.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 75
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 75
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [TinyImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL110_.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 110
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 110
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [MediumImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL._SL160_.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 160
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 160
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [LargeImage] => Array
                                        (
                                            [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51EN7cswSYL.jpg
                                            [Height] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 500
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                            [Width] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [_] => 500
                                                    [Units] => pixels
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Category] => primary
                                )

                        )

                    [ItemAttributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Binding] => Electronics
                            [Brand] => Kindle
                            [CatalogNumberList] => Array
                                (
                                    [CatalogNumberListElement] => 53-000406
                                )

                            [EAN] => 2609000005244
                            [EANList] => Array
                                (
                                    [EANListElement] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 2609000005244
                                            [1] => 2609000006326
                                            [2] => 2609000009471
                                            [3] => 0848719003796
                                            [4] => 2609000009136
                                            [5] => 2609000005497
                                            [6] => 2609000006364
                                            [7] => 2720320491521
                                            [8] => 2609000006388
                                            [9] => 2609000009327
                                        )

                                )

                            [Feature] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Stunning 1280x800 HD display with rich color and deep contrast from any viewing angle
                                    [1] => Exclusive Dolby audio and dual driver stereo speakers for crisp, booming sound without distortion
                                    [2] => Ultra-fast Wi-Fi- dual-antenna, dual-band Wi-Fi for 35% faster downloads and streaming
                                    [3] => Over 22 million movies, TV shows, songs, magazines, books, audiobooks, and popular apps and games
                                )

                            [ItemDimensions] => Array
                                (
                                    [Height] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 40
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                    [Length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 760
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 87
                                            [Units] => hundredths-pounds
                                        )

                                    [Width] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 540
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                )

                            [Label] => Amazon Digital Services, Inc
                            [ListPrice] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 19900
                                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                    [FormattedPrice] => $199.00
                                )

                            [Manufacturer] => Amazon Digital Services, Inc
                            [Model] => 53-000406
                            [MPN] => 0379
                            [PackageDimensions] => Array
                                (
                                    [Height] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 140
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                    [Length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 1010
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 115
                                            [Units] => hundredths-pounds
                                        )

                                    [Width] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => 740
                                            [Units] => hundredths-inches
                                        )

                                )

                            [PackageQuantity] => 1
                            [PartNumber] => 0379
                            [ProductGroup] => Amazon Devices
                            [ProductTypeName] => ABIS_ELECTRONICS
                            [Publisher] => Amazon Digital Services, Inc
                            [ReleaseDate] => 2012-09-14
                            [Studio] => Amazon Digital Services, Inc
                            [Title] => Kindle Fire HD 7", Dolby Audio, Dual-Band Wi-Fi, 16 GB - Includes Special Offers
                            [UPC] => 848719003796
                            [UPCList] => Array
                                (
                                    [UPCListElement] => 848719003796
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I know it's kinda long. but I am getting inconsistent results, sometimes processing the code works perfectly, but sometimes it triggers an error **"Cannot use string offset"**. Why is this happening?

*PS: The array response came from Amazon Product Advertising API, I know this is not an important detail, incase you are wondering :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you are getting from amazon is not same for all the products. Some products have some extra data and some dont have those

Eg: product attributes will vary for different products (t-shirt, mobile phone)

some products may have offer price

(If offer price is there for a product it will be a in 'offer' ['item']['offer'], So first you check for this offset if it is not there take the price from attributes tage(price will be shown there in amazon response))

So before you print or process the data, Check for the key in array get the value only in key exists.

**In your case :**

```
$result = $response['Items']['Item'];
$html = "";
foreach( $result as $k => $v ){
  if($k == "MediumImage"){
      echo $v['URL'];
  }
}
```

**What you have done is wrong** you will not get $v["MediumImage"] here.

Comment: I know that part :) I'm just getting the same attribute from Amazon so no need to worry about the keys of the array. Actually the error occurs when I try to search an ASIN not an actual word. Check the array response that I wrote above.

Comment: what you have done is wrong you will not get $v["MediumImage"] here. please see the edited anser :)

Comment: If more than one item are there then I guess your code will work.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! :) So how would I know if I will only get one item? :)

Comment: get the count of $response['Items']['Item'], ie `count($response['Items']['Item'])`

Comment: OR $response['Items']['TotalResults'] will give you total result count, It ts there in amazon response array :)

Comment: $response['Items']['TotalResults']

Comment: Wow! That worked! I will try to integrate your code above, but the $response['Items']['TotalResults'] worked perfectly! I haven't thought of that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that their response is inconsistent (like Google Maps API seems to be sometimes). Therefore the line

```
$image = "<img src='".$v['MediumImage']['URL']."' />";
```

... will not contain the `MediumImage` part. What I'd do is to try rewrite that line like this:

```
if (is_array($v['MediumImage']) && isset($v['MediumImage']) && isset($v['MediumImage']['URL'])) {
    $image = "<img src='".$v['MediumImage']['URL']."' />";
} else {
    // handle non-existing MediaImage URL here
}
```